# Edit entire row in a DataGridView (not only one cell)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Could somebody advice how to do this?

Currently i have :

1. DataGridView with four columns - Text1 | Text2 | EditButton | SaveButton
2. When i click on the Text1 it becomes an editable field and i can
   change its value
3. Then i try to edit Text2 but the click on this cell saves my changes in Text1

**The issue is** : when i try to edit second field (Text2) the first one (Text1) loses the focus, exits edit mode and saves changes that i made meanwhile i want to save all changes in a row simultaneously.

What i want to implement :

1. I press EditButton and all cells becomes editable so i can change value of any cell in a row
2. I change value of Text1, then value of Text2
3. And only when i press SaveButton it saves made changes

**The question is** : how to keep all cells in a row in edit mode until i press specific button?

Comment: This link may be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4esb49b4(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @davidsbro : i do not have any data source - i am simply transferring some data from one window to another using sockets, so example with data source it is not what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i know it may look a bit messy but this seems to be simplest solution i could come up to - display TextBox over each read only cell when grid is going to edit mode :

```
public void DisplayEditors(DataGridView grid, DataGridViewRow row)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.ReadOnly == false)
                {
                    var place = grid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex, true);
                    var name = string.Format("EDITOR-{0}-{1}", cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex);
                    var editor = grid.Controls.Find(name, false).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (editor == null)
                    {
                        editor = new TextBox();

                        (editor as TextBox).Name = name;

                        grid.Controls.Add(editor);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        editor.Show();
                    }

                    editor.Size = place.Size;
                    editor.Location = place.Location;
                    editor.Text = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a custom DataGridView like this

```
public class CustomDGV : DataGridView
{
    private object _cellValue;
    private Dictionary<int, object[]> _pendingChanges;

    public CustomDGV()
    {
        _pendingChanges = new Dictionary<int, object[]>();
    }

    protected override void OnCellBeginEdit(DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the value of the cell before edit
        _cellValue = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

        // If there's already a pending change for that cell, display the edited value
        if (_pendingChanges.ContainsKey(e.RowIndex))
        {
            this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = _pendingChanges[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex];
        }

        base.OnCellBeginEdit(e);
    }

    protected override void OnCellEndEdit(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Adds the edited value of the cell into a dictionary
        if (!_pendingChanges.ContainsKey(e.RowIndex))
        {
            _pendingChanges.Add(e.RowIndex, new object[this.ColumnCount]);
        }

        _pendingChanges[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex] = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

        // Display the "old" value
        this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = _cellValue;
    }

    public void SavePendingChanges(int rowIndex)
    {
        if (_pendingChanges.ContainsKey(rowIndex))
        {
            // Gets the pending changes for that row
            var rowData = _pendingChanges[rowIndex];
            // Update every cell that's been edited
            for(int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rowData[i] != null)
                    this[i, rowIndex].Value = rowData[i];
            }
            // Removes the pending changes from the dictionary once it's saved
            _pendingChanges.Remove(rowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

And on CellContentClick you can call SavePendingChanges()

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3) // Save button
        {
            dataGridView1.SavePendingChanges(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion though it is not my case because i am updating values in a grid each second so keeping changes in a dictionary is not enough for me because i also need to hide updating values while grid is in edit mode (for user it will be confusing to see that value is still changing even though he already edited it)